# How to apply style-sheet only to a particular select box in form in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have made a form in which I want to apply a different style to a particular Select Box in that form.

```
 <style>
 select#complaintSource 
 { 
 @import url("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css");   
 @import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");        
 }
 </style>


    @if(select)
     {  
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    }
    @endif

    <form>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="complaintSource">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     </select>
    </form>
```

I want to apply the Style to this particular Select Box . At the moment it is applying to all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method that We Can Include Style Sheet to only select box in View. If you have applied the Style Sheet then you have to change CSS or Style your page accordingly. That's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that the OP here can't just do:

```
<style>
select#complaintSource {
/*enter Bootstrap [select] code only here, such as:*/
display: block;
width: 100px; /*and so on */

/*enter your custom select code here*/
color: green;
}
</style>
```

Where 'enter code here' would have 1) the relevant lines from Bootstrap, since it's only for select, and 2) the custom styles for it, placed inside as CSS.

Comment: <style>
                        select#complaintSource { 
                                <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
                        }</style>. Not Working. @Ashwin Anandani

Comment: Ah @Raghav, should've been more clear there --> when using CSS, we cannot add <link> since it is HTML. So instead you have two options: 1) take the CSS out of the files themselves directly (as you do not need the entirety of Bootstrap's CSS files), or 2) don't use your if(select) code up top and simply paste your <link> code before your <form> begins.

Comment: <style>
        select#complaintSource 
        { 
                import url("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css");   
                import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");        
        }
</style>. This will work or Not

Comment: Good call! Almost - you're just missing the "@" before import, see here for more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp

Comment: I have applied @. After that, It is not working.@Ashwin Anandani

Comment: Hmm.. the only thing I can pull out that could be messing it up are:
1) Have you used closing quotations on your code up there? OR try without quotations at all
2) Perhaps add <style type="text/css"> to the opening tag
3) The only other thing is perhaps the file link is not correct? (when I click your link above, I'm redirected to the link + an extra " at the end) OR that actually you may have to use https:// with the s

Comment: Here Is the Js Fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/rahulpamnani/oj5mmyq4/6/   @Ashwin Anandani.